# Facing Py4JJavaError while executing PySpark command

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am new to PySpark and tried to execute PySpark command and getting an error. Below are the commands I tried without issues.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext

SS = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").appName("ProjectData").config("spark.executor.memory","1g").getOrCreate()

sc = SS.sparkContext

testData = sc.parallelize([3,6,4,2])

testData.count()
```

When I load the CSV file from my local file system, I am facing the following error while running the below code. I do not understand the error. Is there any issue in the Python Java connector and how to resolve this?

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/vijee/Python/mc1.csv")
rdd1.count()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-984ccbd7a083> in <module>
----> 1 rdd1.count()

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1139         3
   1140         """
-> 1141         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1142 
   1143     def stats(self):

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in sum(self)
   1130         6.0
   1131         """
-> 1132         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1133 
   1134     def count(self):

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
   1001         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
   1002         # to the final reduce call
-> 1003         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
   1004         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
   1005 

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    887         """
    888         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 889             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    890         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    891 

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:776)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2164)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
    ... 53 more
```

Also below is the set up made in my .bashrc file in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export PATH="/home/vijee/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/vijee/hadoop-2.7.7
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH="$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

export SPARK_HOME=/home/vijee/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH="$PATH:/home/vijee/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin"

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/vijee/anaconda3/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/vijee/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: The JVM might have crashed due to lack of memory. Try setting `spark.driver.memory` to a higher value.